# Contenteditable <div> inside a <td> becomes un-editabale after assigning text to <td> in IE

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer

My objective is to show a table with its cells populated with values from a database and make them editable in IE.

I am using contenteditable attribute for this but as explained [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms533690(v=vs.85).aspx), you cannot assign contenteditable to `<td>`'s and have to use a `<div>` or `<span>` inside them.

That works great as long as you haven't assigned a text to the `<td>` but as soon as you do that, it becomes uneditable.
I have tried wrapping the whole table inside a contenteditable `<div>` but that makes the table headers editable as well and I haven't found a way to override that. Plus, tabbing goes out of whack and you need to add new functions to handle tabbing between `<td>`'s.
I have tried to explain the behavior here [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y8at2vht/1/).

Can you please tell me what is the best way to accomplish this? Needless to say Chrome handles it perfectly, only IE is problematic.

Thanks much!

Comment: use more specific selectors. Table one is invalid html having `<div>` as child of `<table>`  and you are wiping out the inner `<div>` in `<td>`

Comment: Thank you for your input charlietfl. How else can I make the `<td>` editable in IE? All my searches on web points to the fact that I need to add a contenteditable `<span>` or `<div>` inside `<td>`. For other browsers, I could make the `<td>`s themselves contenteditable but it doesn't work in IE, as it is stated in the link in my original post.

Comment: Because the link you provided is wiping out the contenteditable in the td when you use `text()` on the cell. Your selectors are so hard to read that I don't think you realize what they are actually targeting. Should work fine using valid html and proper targets

Comment: Ok, so setting the text wipes out the contenteditable attribute. Is there a way to restore it then? Or is there another method besides text() to populate the cells without wiping out that attribute?

Comment: set the text of the `<div>` not the `<td>` or use `html()` method to set text inside a contenteditable div in the `<td>`

Comment: Aah, thank you so much! Seems like the logical thing to do but I was so wrapped up in targeting the cells by column and row that I didn't consider addressing them by the `<div>`s inside. BTW, using html() doesn't work either. You have made my day! Thanks again.

Comment: using html() would work fine...if you use the right html

Comment: Can you please expand on your comment about using the right html? Are you referring to using html5?